How to convert a convolutional to a fully connected ones in PyTorch with integrated bias
How to add a bias to the Toepletiz matrix?
The following approach just shows how to convert the kernel matrix such that
Y = A*X

But I want something like
Y = A*X + B


For the bias you would just use the bias weights from the conv layer. The bias does not come from the convolution kernel weights

Yes, and in which format?
